# Dynamic memory allocation when using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having an issue with what seems to be a dynamic allocation of memory. (This will be a little difficult to explain so bear with me.)

Using tkinter, PythonWin and Python 2.6.
I have written a program in which the user can add multiple rows and columns of Option Menu widgets, each menu having hundreds of selections. Once they have created all the rows and columns they want, they can save all their selections to a file. When the tool is reopened, there is an option to read in a file of data to recreate all the option menu choices they have previously selected. The tool works very well when recreating these rows and columns of option menus selections unless the number of rows is very large (say over 200 rows – though there is nothing magical about the 200). 
The tool crashes when the rebuild process is ‘appending’ another option menu to a growing list of option menus.

The following is an example of how I add an Option Menu widget to a list:

```
self.omPlaces = []
for i in range(len(numberOfRows)):
    self.omPlaces.append(OptionMenu(self.frame, self.placesVar[i], *self.placesList, command = lambda widgObj=self.omPlaces,quad=(i*4)+2, arg3=True, arg4=True:self._displayProperWidget(widgObj,quad,arg3,arg4)))
    self.omPlaces[i].config(width=120, font=('Arial', 9), activebackground='ghost white', disabledforeground="gray80", indicatoron=0, compound='right', image=self.arrow)
    self.omPlaces[i].grid(row=nextRow, padx=2, column=3)
```

My question: Is there a way to handle the memory for a program that can grow very large, say up to 1GB? (Not the file output but the self-expanding GUI itself.) I don't believe prebuilding these  lists can be done since there are unique arguments to be passed to the 'command = lambda' etc...

Comment: When the program crashes, do you get an error message? What is the error message? Also, the formatting of your code is incorrect. Please take the time to get the formatting correct, since indentation is critical in understanding exactly what your code is doing.

Comment: The only thing that occurs prior to the crash is a small TK Error popup window appears void of any message. (Just a red X and an OK button.) Click OK and everything goes away.
As for the indentation, I just posted a small snippet of the code. It is during one of these 'appends' that it is crashing. I do not believe the append is the issue as much as that is where the memory is being trashed.
BTW, what is wrong with the indentation?
Thanks

Comment: it looks like someone else fixed the indentation for you. Originally, there was no indentation at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now any ideas about how to handle dynamic memory allocation during widget creation?

Comment: i don't quite understand what you're asking. Python gives no way to "handle dynamic memory allocation" - it does all that for you via the garbage collector. There must be more to your problem than what is in your question, I've successfully created thousands of widgets without memory problems. I suggest you create the smallest working example you can that creates all these widgets so we can see exactly what you are doing. For example, are you using threads? How big is self.placesList, etc.

Comment: You seem very knowledgeable about Python and Tkinter so I was wondering if I could send you the files to review. The code is too long to post here. My hopes would be that you could review the files and let me know if I have done anything that is inherently 'dangerous' for coding. This was my first program but since requirements were unrestrained, code was added upon code. If you agree to look, how can I send you the files?

Comment: One additional note is that the main GUI does not hang when creating a large amount of OptionMenus but when I parent.withdraw the first GUI and open a second window with multiple OptionMenus. When the subFrame is opened is when the tool hangs (while attempting to build all the rows of OptionMenus for that second window.)